# Font Rendering?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I am inserting some Chinese, Japanese, and Arabic type (IE: `地球の平和` ) into a page. They render fine for myself yet I do not know if they will render on other computers.

I have Creative Suites on this computer with the CS fonts installed and I am fairly certain that the software added those language fonts or are they standard and anyone who loads the page will see those fonts.

If they are not standard is my best bet to use the `@font-face` to render them?

Comment: Standard PC these days can render Unicode. The worst that should happen is that they fall back to some other font than the one you specified and that it looks a little off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various font substitution engines are *generally* good at figuring out which font should be used to display them; the only thing you should worry about is if you want to use serif or sans serif for the rendering (which usually become mincho and gothic, and their Arabic equivalents).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Long as the font renders is a legible form I am okay. Thanks!

Comment: The big issue is getting your encoding right all the way down the pipe.