# Can UTF-8 handle any language?

Tags: php, utf-8

If I set the HTML document charset to UTF-8, the database encoding to UTF-8, and pass UTF-8 as charset to various PHP functions, will that make my site be able to handle any language?

Comment: What does "handle any language" mean? Do you understand things like right-to-left text, combining characters, compatability normalization, Unicode casing, Unicode collation, Unicode linebreaking, or East Asian wide characters?  If not, then probably not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be able to handle any language covered by Unicode, but not ones such as tlhIngan Hol or Sindarin.

Comment: Perhaps you should instead google what alphabets Unicode supports ;) Also remember, that even though you application might be ready to accept text in any alphabet covered by Unicode, there's still issue of fonts - due to size constraints and/or effort most of them don't support entire Unicode range.

Comment: In fact, I don't know of a single font that does. Fortunately [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599451/font-rendering).

Comment: Actually, Sindarin is on its way, because the Tengwar are in the Unicode roadmap. You can already use them if you use the private use area. I have a module that gives custom named characters and properties to these, so you can say `"\N{TENGWAR LETTER QUESSE}"` for a named character, or `\p{In_Tengwar_Vowels}` for a character property. Pretty slick.

Comment: Unicode doesn’t define languages.  It defines scripts. As for fonts, stear clear of Microsoft.  Modern OpenType fonts, like Arno Pro from Adobe, can do well for Western sets, but you will need different fonts for different scripts: no one font has them all. Junicode is pretty code for proportional, Everson Mono for constant width, and Symbola for emoji.